# Hibernate delete doesn't execute

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using a test spring boot project to learn some hibernate. I have 2 interfaces extending CrudRepository - Address and Student both annotated with @Transactional and @Repository. Many students should share the same address.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface AddressDao extends CrudRepository<Address, Integer> {}


@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int addressId;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipcode;
```

etc.

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long studentId;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 70)
private String studentName;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "studentAddress")
private Address studentAddress;
```

etc.
and the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainSpringBootClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
StudentDao studentDao;

@Autowired
AddressDao addressDao;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainSpringBootClass.class, args);
}


@Override
@Transactional
public void run(String... args) {

    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
    addressDao.findAll().forEach(list::add);

    Address address;

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        address = list.get(0);
    } else {
        address = new Address().withCity("London").withZipcode("W1J 9LL")
                .withStreet("Piccadilly").withState("UK");
    }

    Student student1 = new Student().withName("Ann").withAddress(address);
    Student student2 = new Student().withName("James").withAddress(address);

    studentDao.save(student1);
    studentDao.save(student2);

    addressDao.delete(1);
    addressDao.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

Problem is every time I run this code 2 new students are added and I don't see addressDao.delete(1) being executed, no exception is thrown, no log from hibernate is printed that it tries to delete the record. Also transaction is not rolled back.
I can see both addressDao.delete(1) and exception if I remove (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) from Student.java but it also means I have to manually save address first before saving student.
What do I do wrong?

Edit:
I added 
 Long removeByCity(String city);
to my AddressDao and replaced addressDao.delete(1) with it. I see it returns 1 so looks like it gets executed but I still don't get any exception here.
I'm getting exception only if I don't use save before.

Comment: can you share your implementation of AddressDao?

Comment: I edited the question. StudentDao looks the same except it uses Long, not Integer.

Comment: do you have your getters and setters on each entity? If not, I believe that there is the problem. And also, as Junbang Huang said, could you share you DAO's and the CrudRepository please? Maybe there is also a problem there.

Comment: yes, I have getters/setters, didn't include them for brevity. 
CrudRepository comes from org.springframework.data.repository.

Comment: Can i ask why you used "@Transactional" and "@Repository" in the address and student DAO instead of @RepositoryRestResource? Maybe by changing this the problem solves.

Comment: Do we really need `@Transactional` on the `run` mehod?

Comment: are you sure you have an address with id 1?

Comment: @Pete maybe not. I wanted it to rollback automatically in case of error.
JunbangHuang I'm sure. If started with an empty tables it will be created, then reused

Comment: try changing the following code. addressDao.delete(address.getId());

Comment: no change. I still see:
Hibernate: insert into student (student_address, student_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (student_address, student_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select address0_.address_id as address_1_0_, address0_.city as city2_0_, address0_.state as state3_0_, address0_.street as street4_0_, address0_.zipcode as zipcode5_0_ from address address0_
org.ms.hibernate.bo.Address@66f5a5f5

no attempt to delete

Comment: I'm not useing rest here. Transactional comes from javax.transaction and Repository from spring

Comment: Might be because it is [re-persisted by a cascaded `PERSIST` operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840903/silently-ignored-remove). This [blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/delete-with-hibernate) might also be helpful.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Thank you, I see now un-scheduling entity deletion [[org.ms.hibernate.bo.Address#1]] in the logs.

Comment: That would also mean that if I want to see my exception I'd need to delete in a different session.